# endAdornment arrow taking too much space with the last character in Material-UI Autocomplete

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
<Autocomplete
  {...defaultProps}
  id="disable-close-on-select"
  disableCloseOnSelect
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="disableCloseOnSelect" variant="standard" />
  )}
/>
```

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/4i0st?file=/demo.js) is the sandbox link.

`endAdornment` arrow taking too much space with the last character in Material-UI `Autocomplete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `padding-right` by targeting the element with the class [`MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot`](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/#:%7E:text=.MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot). You also need to use the double ampersand `&&` to [increase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64486501/9449426) the CSS specificity so the property can be overridden:

```
import Autocomplete, { autocompleteClasses } from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={top100Films}
      inputValue="looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text"
      sx={{
        width: 300,
        [`&& .${autocompleteClasses.inputRoot}`]: {
          paddingRight: 2, // change this value to your preference
        }
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: this is not working. last character of input we type and arrow should have very less space

Comment: @PrateekPareek try lowering the `padding-right` to say 2. Does that work for you, or is it not working at all?

Comment: it is not working at all

Comment: @PrateekPareek what MUI version are you using?

Comment: actually position of arrow is absolute and it is taking fixed gap from left . we need that it adjust according to the length of the characters. like if a word is length of 2 and another word is length of 10 but the position of arrow is static. it does not adjust

Comment: 4.12.1 version of mui i am using

Comment: @PrateekPareek The arrow is always static. But you want to move to the left if the text is shorter? what happen when the `TextField` is empty?

Comment: yes right i want to move that arrow on left if the text is shorter . in empty text we will give a default space